# MySQL NodeJS: MySQL queries executing together

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, asynchronous

In the `Controller.js` file below, I want to have the second mysql query wait for the first query to complete and then use the data stored in `foundUser` from the first query.

I am having a hard time applying `async await` because the second query is receiving an empty object because it executes along with the first query.

**Service.js**

```js
addUser: (data) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mysqlpool.query(`insert into requests_team(from_id, to_id)
                value(?,?)`,
            [
            data.from_id,
            data.to_id
            ],
            (error, results, fields)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(results);
            }
    );
    })
},
```

**Controller.js**

```js
addUser: async(req, res) =>{
    const body = req.body;
    let errors = {};
    let foundUser = {}
    const queryOne = await mysqlpool.query('SELECT id, email FROM registration WHERE email = ?', [body.email], (error, result)=>{
        if(error){
        console.log(error)
        }
        if(result.length > 0){
        foundUser = result
        }

    });

    const queryTwo = await mysqlpool.query(`This is where I want to use the value stored in foundUser ${foundUser[0].id}`, (error, result) => {
        if(error){
        console.log(error);
        }
        addUser(body, (err, results) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({
            success: 0,
            message: 'Error'
            })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: 1
        })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
addUser: async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    let errors = {};
    let foundUser = {}
    const queryOne = await mysqlpool.query('SELECT id, email FROM registration WHERE email = ?', [body.email]);

    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
        foundUser = result
    
        const queryTwo = await mysqlpool.query(`This is where I want to use the 
        value stored in foundUser ${foundUser[0].id}`)

        // Do stuff with the queryTWo response here
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. However, I tried that but it did not work. I updated my code above based on what you suggested so you can take a look and see if I did something wrong.

Comment: @Hoopoe_Programming You should not use callback functions when using async/await. Move the callback block code below the main query as shown in my code. Though I am not sure if the library you're using returns Promises.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn’t work. For example when I try to print queryOne in console.log it doesn’t show me the data I need in order to assign the value to foundUser so queryTwo can use that data. And if queryTwo is successful the data will then be posted to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you try to use `async await` with `callbacks`, async await only works with promises, or generator but that's another story. Getting back to the topic you have alot of options to fix this. let's use the easiest.

There is a nodejs module call `util` it comes with node, so you just need to import it at the top

```js
import { promisify } from "util";
// const promisify = require("util").promisify;

const myCoolVarName = promisify(mysqlpool.query);
//module.exports = async function addUser (req, res) {
export async function addUser (req, res) {
  try {
  // instead of using mysqlpool and stuff use `myCoolVarName`
  // PS: I mean dont have to call it that ... well getting back
  const resultQuery1 = await myCoolVarName("SELECT CURRENT_DATE()");
  const resultQuery2 = await myCoolVarName("SELECT * FROM table WHERE row = ?", resultQuery1);

  return res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({message: 'we broke or so'})
  }
}
```

It should work, but if you want to use mysql with node Like the Gods
https://medium.com/@enetoOlveda/how-to-connect-expressts-with-mysql-professional-fea43bfa86d3

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected. Some libraries work with promises as well as callbacks. The question explicitly mentioned about promises. So I suggested how they can use async-await in my answer.